# LINQ to CRM fails while left-joining more than two tables

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-online, dataverse

I have a scenario where there is need to retrieve data from multiple tables in Dataverse, below is a sample query (there are 7 tables involved in Join, for simplicity i have included only 3).

```
var query = from location in organizationContext.LocationData
            join address in organizationContext.Address on location.LocationId equals address.locationAddressRelation.Id 
                into addressGrp from addressJ in addressGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()  //Commenting this and
            join contact in organizationContext.Contact on location.LocationId equals contact.locationContactRelation.Id    
                into contactGrp from contactJ in contactGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()  // and commenting this makes the query work
            select new {location.Id, address.Id, contact.Id};
```

Executing the above query results in the below error,

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The method
> 'Join' cannot follow the method 'SelectMany' or is not supported. Try
> writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the
> 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported
> methods.)'

This could be a limitation of the Linq to CRM provider, i want to know any alternatives to the above requirement.

Thanks.